# Calculating limits of trignometric funtions

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

How do proceed in calculating the limits of following function.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1+\cos(\frac{x\pi}{2})}{1+\sin(\frac{x\pi}{2})}$$

I know that the value of $1 + \cos(\frac{x\pi}{2})$ and $1 + \sin(\frac{x\pi}{2})$ will always differ by $1$.

However as $\cos(\frac{x\pi}{2})$ and $\sin(\frac{x\pi}{2})$ are oscillating I am not finding any luck in calculating it.

Is there any rule that I am missing or the $\lim$ simply doesn't exist.

Thanks.

Comment: the denominator vanishes when $x = 4k-1$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Your function is periodic, and undefined for many values of $x.$  You can use either of these facts to prove that the limit does not exist.

Comment: Many times it is interesting to graph the function and see what is going on. That's also the case here. Then you can easily see that the limit cannot exist. If graphing is not an acceptable answer, at least now you know what to look for to establish your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Evaluate the limit along the following two sequences:
$\{4k\}_{k\geq 0}$ and $\{4k+1\}_{k\geq 0}$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$x_n=2n\pi $$
$$y_n=(2n+1)\pi$$